# Change the signing team in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I have created a project in Xcode which has a Bundle ID of "**com.example.programOne**". The team under this project is personal i.e; **ABC**. Now I want to change the personal team in this existing project with a different Bundle ID, let's say **com.example.programTwo** and different personal team i.e; **ABCD**. I have created an apple ID for ABCD and linked with Xcode in preferences, but I am not able to assign this project to ABCD with different Bundle ID.

It gives me warning:

1. Failed to create provisioning profile.

There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

2. No profiles for '**com.example.programTwo**' were found

Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching '**com.example.programTwo**'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check atleast one device is registered in your Apple account. 
Include atleast one device in your provisioning profile.

or after adding a device in Apple developer account, Please check this option so that Xcode will create a provisioning profile for you. It will take care of running in your device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! Let me check.

Comment: Do I must own an iPhone in order to build my application and it's impossible to release an app without it? @Santo My only device is the Mac i'm developing with...

Comment: @TheUnreal Yes, you may need the use of an iPhone. It is because, when you upload the application to iTunes, you are uploading an archive. And to build up that archive you need a real device. I hope I made the point clear.

Comment: ^ You don't need a physical phone. You can also choose "Generic Build Device"